# Big window container in Windows to manage all windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, container

This is a bit difficult to explain but I will try my best.

I am looking for a software that can be parent to any Windows application I like and will manage its size.

For example there is a software called IntelliJ, where you can open basically any time of text file ( .txt, .java, .php anything.. ) and you can divide the view in this application in the way you like and just move around the borders to resize the files that are open. A screen shot can explain better:

[image]

In this image, what I show with the green arrows are the borders I mention. I can simply drag them to right or left, and the relevant windows will automatically get bigger or smaller.

What I am looking for is, imagine a software that can be parent to the windows application I choose. So instead of text files, imagine you have internet explorer on the left handside, notepad++ on righthandside, utorrent in the lower part etc...

Hope what I am asking is clear,
Regards.

Comment: I have seen many questions asking for software here.

Comment: Software questions are fine, software recommendations are not. http://superuser.com/help/on-topic (see the bullet `asking for a shopping or product recommendation` under `it is not about`).

Comment: Ok, imagine I ask this question like this: Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: @KorayTugay That would be perfect. If you edited your question and phrased it like that, it would likely stay open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a [Tiling window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager). Windows itself has a basic tile-function but doesn't keep the windows tiled.

On the Wiki page [Tiling window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager) you'll find some [Third-party addons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager#Third-party_addons). Although lots of these don't have links to the utilities i did find these articles for [Blumb](http://www.abctrick.net/2011/11/plumb-aligns-resizes-active-windows.html) and [DeskLayer](http://www.abctrick.net/2011/07/desklayer-for-windows-auto-arrange.html).

I tried [DeskLayer](http://www.lkrprojects.com/home.html) and it does automatically rearrange the windows when you resize one. It does not "contain" all the windows in a big "container" but it does keep you windows all tiled the way you want. (So see the big screen/desktop as a container ;) You can see an example video of this [here](http://www.lkrprojects.com/videos.html).

If that one is not to your liking you can try [Blumb](http://palatialsoftware.com/plumb/) or search the others found on that Wiki-page.

[image: DeskLayer]